# How do I replace &nbsp; with the €-symbol in my order invoice?

Tags: magento-1.9

Recently I changed my €-symbol to "`&nbsp;`" to remove the €-symbol from my front-end store (see screenshot)
[image: Currency settings in my Magento back-end.]

But that also made my Invoice display the "`&nbsp;`" instead of the €-symbol.
[image: Example invoice]
How do I change this back to a €-symbol in my invoice ONLY? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the code please , how did you replaced it ?

Comment: I replaced it without using code. I pasted `&nbsp;` into the currency settings in the backend as you can see in the first screenshot in my post.

Comment: I know , but the line of code that shows that change , can you paste it ?

Comment: Why not let that fild empty , instead of adding a backspace ?

Comment: yeah that make sense

Comment: I can't show you the line of code that changed, since I don't ever work in the code lines. Also, I can't leave that input field empty, it needs a value that's why I added the `&nbsp;` character as suggested on other threads.

Comment: make sure that your input file is correctly encoded in UTF-8